# PHP htaccess getting values from $_GET

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm faced with this htaccess issue. I need to get search input values through $_GET['s'] and I had already added this 
`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?action=$1` 
to my htaccess file which helps me get a friendly url like www.url.com/search/. 
But I want to pass another $_GET['s'] to the link through search forms and I don't want to add them like www.url.com/search/search-text rather I want this: www.url.com/search/?s=search-text. 
please how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is tell apache that you want the query string to be appended. The easiest way to do this is to add the following to the end of your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note, I've also added [`L` (last)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) which you probably want. [`QSA`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) stands for *query string append* and does what you'd expect.

When I visit `mysite.com/test/?test2=true` and `var_dump()` `$_GET` I see the following output:

```
array (size=2)
  'action' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'test2' => string 'true' (length=4)
```